# Is the breathing sound effect supposed to be alerting me of something?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm currently playing as [Gaige](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Gaige) and I noticed after sprinting for awhile [as expected] I started hearing a breathing noise, but I continued. Apparently I've got unlimited sprint? the game never slowed me down (while sprinting I mean) is this a bug? In most of the games I've played when I hear the breathing sound effect it means that I can't sprint for a little while and have to let it recharge.

If I do have unlimited sprint then why do I hear the breathing sound effect, is it just for atmosphere or what?

Comment: I've never stopped or slowed down while running with Gaige. I suppose the breathing is nothing more than decoration (like foot steps) and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: It's just a sound effect...

Comment: @demure It's not immediately obvious. Many games have trained me to link heavy breathing to running out of sprinting power, so when I hear heavy breathing in a game I naturally assume I will no longer be able to sprint. It's counter-intuitive to how other games have trained me, although I have no issues with the effect since I never noticed a change in gameplay.

Comment: @SadlyNot Thank you :). Anyway ya I originally thought it was letting me know that I was running out of energy (to sprint), but I guess it was just atmospheric touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is only a sound effect. I have heard it with other characters as well, but never with Zer0.